# all homepage links are redirecting in localhost/xampp/

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I am trying to load php script downloaded from git. Home page is fine.
When I click any of home page link, page is redirecting to `localhost/xampp/`

Please help me. This is very important to my project.
My `.htaccess` is:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$



RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)/$ /?page=$1&act=$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^upload/([^/]*)$ /?page=upload&act=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^torrents/([0-9]+)$ /?page=torrents&next=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrents/cat/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&catid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^torrents/cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&catid=$1&next=$2 [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^torrents/search/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&search=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrents/search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&search=$1&next=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrents/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&sortedBy=$1&axis=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrents/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&next=$1&sortedBy=$2&axis=$3 [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^torrents/cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&catid=$1&sortedBy=$2&axis=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^torrents/cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrents&catid=$1&next=$2&sortedBy=$3&axis=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^torrent-detail/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrent-detail&id=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrent-detail/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrent-detail&id=$1&urlTitle=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^torrent-edit/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrent-edit&id=$1&urlTitle=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^torrent-delete/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=torrent-delete&id=$1&hash=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)$ /?page=download&hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/([^/]*)$ /?page=rss&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/([0-9]+)$ /?page=account&next=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admincp/users/([0-9]+)$ /?page=admincp&act=users&next=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is path of your web site files in the server?

Comment: It's in my local server. Path http://localhost/torrento/

Comment: What is exact URL you're entering in browser that is creating problems?

Comment: http://localhost/user_profile.php

Comment: Is redirecting to http://localhost/xampp/